# apt-get returns Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/main b43-fwcutter i386 1:013-2 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]

Tags: wireless, apt

I'm new to the forum and I'm running a new install of Ubuntu 10.10 on my old Dell D610. Synaptic Manager will only download 117 of 142 packages, and when I try to download/install from there or a command line I get the same error below.

I need to get my wireless working, and the drivers that came with the ISO do not include the bcm4318 I need.

Thanks for any help!!!

```
dan@dan-Latitude-D610:~$ sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter
[sudo] password for dan: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  fakeroot libgif4 patch
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  b43-fwcutter
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 16.3kB of archives.
After this operation, 81.9kB of additional disk space will be used.
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  b43-fwcutter
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? y
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/main b43-fwcutter i386 1:013-2
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/b/b43-fwcutter/b43-fwcutter_013-2_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
dan@dan-Latitude-D610:~$
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! New questions about [end-of-life](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#End_of_Life_.28EOL.29) Ubuntu releases are considered off-topic as per [the FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq). These old releases are unsupported and their use is not recommended. They don't even get updates for newly discovered security vulnerabilities, which makes using them risky. If you install or upgrade to [a supported release](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#Stable) and this question still applies, please flag and/or comment to request it be reopened.

Comment: See also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release

Answer (score 0):

Go here [b43zip file](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2117874)

Download the b43 zip file to a flash drive then drag and drop the file to your Ubuntu desktop. Right-click it and select Extract Here. Open a terminal and do:

```
sudo mkdir /lib/firmware/b43
sudo cp Desktop/b43/* /lib/firmware/b43
sudo rmmod -f b43
sudo rmmod -f ssb
sudo modprobe b43
```

if you have not installed any other wireless driver your wireless should now be working.

You are still going to have trouble updating 10.10 because it is no longer supported so the repositories are not available.

I found a link that will let you update packages but you need to know these are old packages they are no longer updated either.
[update packages for old releases](http://pogidude.com/2013/how-to-install-packages-for-end-of-life-ubuntu-editions/)

Comment: Wild Man, thanks for the help! I now have wireless... nothing like being untethered.